# Why won't mySQL start?

Tags: mysql, database

I've tried many things said on the internet, also tried to fix it myself, but I don't have any clue, what I could do next. I can't Reinstall it, because there is important data on it.

The log:

htts://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=24, page number=1] log sequence number 300669 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300459.
> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 2 [ERROR] InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to htts://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.
> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 300450; transaction id 214
> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
> 2022-12-31  0:32:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

I've tried updateing the config.
I've tried booting without password.

Comment: Since its important, wheres the backup ?

Comment: Well I have a backup, but I don't want to drive 1h to get the drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently two methods:

1. Modify the value of innodb_force_recovery in the parameter file, and then start the database. If it succeeds, you need to export the data, then recreate the database, and then import the data. If not, refer to the second point.
2. There are some tools, some paid and some free. You can retrieve the data through the ibdata file, and rebuild the database after retrieval.
   Of course it is very important not to delete the data files